# Excel QueryTable getting slower over time until it freezes

Tags: excel, vba, performance, import, freeze

I have a code that runs a query table, imports the data to a sheet, and then runs other code on the data.

I have it on a timer to run every 90 seconds.  Everything works as it should except that over time, it gets slower and slower.  Eventually (after 12 hours or so), it just freezes up completely.  I tried clearing the connections at the end of my code, but that didn't solve the problem.

Any ideas?

```
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www.address.com" _
    , Destination:=sh3.Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "Query"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: Do you ever clean up the connections or just keep adding and adding and adding every time the macro runs? Hit Ctrl+G, then type `?ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count`. What's the number?

Comment: Also, could be `www.address.com` throttling your connection.

Comment: `Dim ii As Long
   For ii = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count To 1 Step -1
       ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(ii).Delete
   Next ii`    ' I have this code at the end of my sub.